# How to make inputs height smaller? Ionic2

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

Normally I dont have any problem stylizing any component, but I cant find a way to make the text input height smaller, is there any way to do that?

```
  <ion-item class="username">
     <ion-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

And css:

```
.username{
  max-height: something;
  height: something;
}
```

`width` property works fine but I cant set the height

I was also trying to modify the input property directly, like:

```
.text-input{
height: something
}
```

or

```
.text-input-md {
height: something
}
```

I have edited every property of input to make it smaller but none works, like its stuck on certain size.

Comment: You have to provide us with some source code or at least show us what you have tried.!

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#the-height-property

Comment: i have added some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target the input as the `ion-input` will later generate an input tag so you can simply do this :

```
.username input{
  max-height: something;
  height: something;
}
```

you may also be more specific by doing this

```
.username input.text-input{
  max-height: something;
  height: something;
}
```

By the way don't forget padding and font size. Try to decrease them if you are trying to make a small height.

Comment: @AnotherChris, i added more info to the answer in order to also consider padding and font size

Comment: In ionic4 When it imported theme/common.scss globally, this works.
but when it imported components/username.scss locally, this doesn't work. you know why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, then you could use

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputsm">Small input</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text">
</div>
```

OR, use the following code in css

```
input[type=text] {height: 60px;}
```